# .NET app is not able to connect to MySQL instance when SSL is enabled

Tags: c#, mysql, .net, ssl

I am trying to connect to MySQL instance from .NET application when SSL is enabled on MySQL instance. I am getting the error `MySql.Data.MySqlClient.MySqlException (0x80004005): Access denied for user 'mysqluser'@'ip_of_mysql' (using password: YES)`.
I have tried with giving `GRANT ALL ON *.* TO 'mysqluser'@'%' WITH GRANT OPTION;` to grant the access to the user. But it didn't worked.

I have tried with the below connection strings to connect to MySQL instance :

```
"server=<ip_of_mysql>;user=mysqluser;database=<Database_name>;port=3306;password=<Password>;SslMode=VerifyFull;SslCa=ca.pem;SslCert=cert.pem;SslKey=key.pem;";
```

```
"server=<ip_of_mysql>;user=mysqluser;database=<Database_name>;port=3306;password=<Password>;SslMode=VerifyCA;SslCa=ca.pem;SslCert=cert.pem;SslKey=key.pem;";
```

The app is able to access the certificate files and there is no problem with the certificate files.

The Versions are as follows :

```
.NET version : 5.0.9
MySQL version : 5.7
MySQL connector .NET version : 8.0.28
```

I have also tried with MySQL command line tool to connect to MySQL SSL enabled server, it is successfully connecting. Using `ASP .NET core 3.1`, it is also able to connect to the Database.

Any help would be greatly appreciated. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Are you using .NET 5.0 on Linux? You may be affected by this breaking change: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/core/compatibility/cryptography/5.0/default-cipher-suites-for-tls-on-linux. If so, a workaround would be to switch to https://www.nuget.org/packages/MySqlConnector/ and supply a `TLS Cipher Suites` value in your connection string, as per https://github.com/mysql-net/MySqlConnector/issues/927#issuecomment-760632481.

Comment: @Charlieface The documentation that you have shared is for MySQL connector .NET version of 6.10 and I am using 8.0.28 version. I followed [this documentation](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/connector-net/en/connector-net-8-0-connection-options.html#connector-net-8-0-connection-options-xprotocol) for the connection string. Also I created this mysql user and I ran `FLUSH PRIVILEGES` also and then `GRANT ALL ON *.* TO 'mysqluser'@'%' WITH GRANT OPTION;`.

Comment: @BradleyGrainger I am using .NET 5.0 on Windows.